# VB6: Automation error The remote procedure call failed

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, shdocvw

In my VB6 application sometimes in some customer PC we get error like

```
Automation error
The remote procedure call failed.
```

The error comes for the code shown below

```
Dim WithEvents Web_popup  As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 
    Set Web_popup = Nothing
    Set Web_popup = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 
    Set ppDisp = Web_popup.Application
```

Also for the below code

```
Dim iE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer iE.Navigate "www.example.com", 4 + 8
iE.Visible = True
```

What may be the reason for these errors? How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should include more information when asking for help.  More importantly, you should point exactly which lines are causing the error.  That being said, it sounds to me that you are not checking the ready state of the download of html to Explorer.  Interacting with a web page before the web page has been completely download will cause this symptom.

If you are checking the ready state, the only other way I was able to produce the error was turning on protected mode in Internet Explorer.  Some websites cause the error when Protected mode is on.